# How to set a proper layout

Tags: java, swing, center, grid-layout

I want to set the layout as the following: 1 column and 5 rows and in the center.
I tried using `GridLayout(5,0)` but it remains in the left, any suggestions how to make it center?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class TestSwingListeners1 {
        private static int cnt1;
        private static int cnt2;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fr1 = new JFrame("Swing Window");
        Container cp;
        JButton bt1;
        JButton bt2;
        cnt1 = 0;
        cnt2 = 0;
        final String scr = null;
        final String wnr = null;
        JButton btOK, btCancel;
        fr1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr1.setSize(200, 200);
        fr1.setResizable(true);
        cp = fr1.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,0));
        // cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        btOK = new JButton("AC Milan");
        btCancel = new JButton("Real Madrid");
        final JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Result: " + cnt1 + "X" + cnt2);
        final JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Last Scorer: " + scr);
        final JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("Winner: " + wnr);
        cp.add(btOK);
        cp.add(btCancel);
        cp.add(lbl1);
        cp.add(lbl2);
        cp.add(lbl3);
        fr1.add(cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(lbl1, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        //lbl1.setText(displayText);

        btOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            cnt1++; 
            lbl1.setText("Result: " + cnt1 + "X" + cnt2);
            lbl2.setText("Last Scorer: AC Milan");

            if(cnt1>cnt2){
                lbl3.setText("Winner: AC Milan");
                }
            else if(cnt1<cnt2){
                lbl3.setText("Winner: Real Madrid");
                }
            else if(cnt1 == cnt2){
                lbl3.setText("Winner: Draw");
                }
            }
        });

        btCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            cnt2++;
            lbl1.setText("Result: " + cnt1 + "X" + cnt2);
            lbl2.setText("Last Scorer: Real Madrid");
            if(cnt1>cnt2){
                lbl3.setText("Winner: AC Milan");
                }
            else if(cnt1<cnt2){
                lbl3.setText("Winner: Real Madrid");
                }
            else if(cnt1 == cnt2){
                lbl3.setText("Winner: Draw");
                }

            }
        });
        fr1.show(); 
       }
  }
```

Comment: this quesion isn't about layout, but as your personal debuger: 1) initialize Container cp; 2) fr1.show(); == fr1.setVisible(true);

Comment: `cp = fr1.getContentPane();` vs `fr1.add(cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);` who will win? :)

Comment: "*..it remains in the left.."*  It does not compile, so I fail to see how it could align anything anywhere.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: For the purposes of asking a layout question, remove all listeners, they're just noise.  Instead of asking a half-formed question about a half-done UI, start with a description of how you want things to end up, written for people who do not know what you're doing already.  Especially for UI questions of this type, plan on writing a *little* program that illustrates your question, and you will get faster and better answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(5, 0);
cp.setLayout(grid);

...

grid.addComponent(btOK, 0, 0);
grid.setComponentAlignment(btOK, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) -- this is a one-stop modern layout manager. You'll never look back at any other layout manager. It saved me tons of time making Swing UIs.